# How do I covert the date in a table from 16-04-06 to 06-APR-16 in oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

My table has date values as yy-mm-dd but I want to make a select statement to select the dates and have them outputted as dd-mon-yy where the month is in letters.

If my table is:

name date

A    17-04-06

B    17-04-11

C    17-04-15

I want the output to be:

A    06-APR-17

B    11-APR-17

C    15-APR-17

How do I convert the table values in my select statement in oracle sql developer?

Comment: What is the data type of your column? Is it a `DATE` or a `VARCHAR2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your column has the `DATE` data type then use `TO_CHAR( column_name, 'DD-MON-RR' )` to output it in your desired format:

```sql
SELECT name,
       TO_CHAR( "DATE", 'DD-MON-RR', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH' ) AS "DATE"
FROM   table_name
```

So, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( name, "DATE" ) AS
SELECT 'A', DATE '2017-04-06' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', DATE '2017-04-11' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', DATE '2017-04-15' FROM DUAL;
```

This outputs:

> ```
> NAME | DATE     
> :--- | :--------
> A    | 06-APR-17
> B    | 11-APR-17
> C    | 15-APR-17
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=27229ad0e3d34271b6dec05c97b9af44)*

Comment: please do not perpetuate the use of the "RR" format, which was _designed_ as a _temp_ fix to buy time in resolving the Y2K bug .... TWENTY YEARS AGO!.  The proper format should be "TO_CHAR( column_name, 'DD-MON-YYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH' ) AS "DATE""

Comment: @EdStevens The OP wanted the output `06-APR-17` so either the `YY` or `RR` format model is appropriate and if they want to reverse the process then parsing `06-APR-98` is typically going to want the `RR` format model more than the `YY` format model. Yes, in this day and age 4-digit years should be used but when the question is "how do I output my date in this format?" then the answer should give it the requested format.

Comment: I disagree.  If the OP had asked how to shoot himself in the foot, would you give him directions on how to do so, or would you point out how that is not really a good idea, and offer a better suggestion to reach his real goal? In this case like this, explain how to_char/to_date works, and point out the issue with 2-digit years.